# ChromeHeadless not starting: timing out when running ng test

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I am working on an Angular 7 (7.2.13) app and am having trouble running `npm run test`, which maps to `ng test --watch=false --browsers=ChromeHeadless`.

I am running [Ubuntu under Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ubuntu/9nblggh4msv6?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) and all of my app-relating command line stuff is done on Ubuntu. This is a requirement of the project, but I've only been here a few weeks and haven't yet found out why!

I have installed ChromeHeadless by following [these instructions](https://gist.github.com/ipepe/94389528e2263486e53645fa0e65578b). I set `CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/chromium-browser` after doing this. However, it looks like ChromeHeadless is having trouble starting:

> 27 05 2019 11:26:40.497:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v4.0.1 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
>
> 27 05 2019 11:26:40.500:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers ChromeHeadless with concurrency unlimited
>   #
>
> 27 05 2019 11:26:40.506:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser ChromeHeadless              27 05 2019 11:27:40.507:WARN [launcher]: ChromeHeadless have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
>
> 27 05 2019 11:27:40.724:INFO [launcher]: Trying to start ChromeHeadless again (1/2).

It tries again a few times, but just times out. I have seen a few posts about turning on verbose logging, but modifying the `captureTimeout` has only the effect of making the process slower!

Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you have [karma-chrome-launcher](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-chrome-launcher) installed?

Answer (score 1):

I solved an issue with this same message caused by a proxy-blocker of the client. I had to set `--proxy-server` flag in my customLauncher in karma.conf.js, so the karma server could get the ChromeHeadless and execute the tests perfectly.

```
karma.conf.js

browsers: ['MyChromeHeadless'], 
    customLaunchers: {
    MyChromeHeadless: {
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: [
          '--no-sandbox',
          '--proxy-bypass-list=*',
          '--proxy-server=http://proxy.your.company'
        ]
      }
    }
```

Comment: --no-sandbox works for me on win server 2019 as ci